# Encrypted socket connection java using RSA (IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 10)

Tags: java, sockets, encryption, encoding, rsa

So i am building a java app which uses a secure RSA connection to deliver data (at the moment i am coding encryption/decryption techniques by hand if there is a library or a better way to do this feel free to write it), it's the first time i am doing this so i don't know that much of the topic.

This is the class i use both on the server and the client side to encrypt/decrypt:

```
public class RSAEncryption extends AsymmetricalEncryption {

    public RSAEncryption() {
        super("RSA");
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] encrypt(String data) {
        Cipher cipher = null;
        byte[] encryptedData = new byte[0];
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, super.sharedKey);
            encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
            encryptedData = Base64.getEncoder().encode(encryptedData);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error on Cipher initialization " + e);
        }
        return encryptedData;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] data) {
        Cipher cipher = null;
        byte[] encryptedData = null;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, super.privateKey);
            encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(data));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encryptedData;
    }

}
```

The RSAEncryption class AsymmetricalEncryption because i would like in the future to implement different encryption protocols.
This is the Server-side connection:

```
public class Connection extends Thread {

    private Socket connection;
    private ObjectInputStream ois;
    private ObjectOutputStream oos;
    private AsymmetricalEncryption encryption;

    public Connection(Socket connection) {
        try {
            this.connection = connection;
            this.ois = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            this.oos = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            encryption = new RSAEncryption();
            // sending the public key
            oos.writeUTF(encryption.encodeBase64PublicKey(encryption.publicKey));
            oos.flush();
            // read sharedKey
            String encodedKey = ois.readUTF();
            encryption.setSharedKey(encryption.decodeBase64PublicKey(encodedKey, "RSA"));
            this.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Connection(Socket connection, String encryptionMethod) {
        try {
            //this.connection = connection;
            this.ois = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            this.oos = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            encryption = AsymmetricalEncryptionFactory.getAsymmetricalEncryption(encryptionMethod);
            // sending the public key
            oos.writeUTF(encryption.encodeBase64PublicKey(encryption.publicKey));
            oos.flush();
            // read sharedKey
            String encodedKey = ois.readUTF();
            encryption.setSharedKey(encryption.decodeBase64PublicKey(encodedKey, encryptionMethod));
            this.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean isRunning = true;
        while(isRunning){
            try {
                byte[] encryptedStringRequest = ois.readAllBytes();
                System.out.println("Encrypted Request: " + encryptedStringRequest);
                byte[] stringRequest = encryption.decrypt(encryptedStringRequest);
                System.out.println("Request: " + new String(stringRequest));
                System.out.println("When you fix the bug remeber to decomment the following two lines of Connection");
                //Request request = Request.parse(this, new JSONObject(stringRequest));
                //RequestQueue.RequestQueue().enqueue(request);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                isRunning = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void response(Response response){
        try {
            byte[] encryptedStringResponse = encryption.encrypt(response.toJSONString().getBytes());
            oos.write(encryptedStringResponse);
            oos.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error during response sending "+ e);
        }
    }

}
```

This is the Client-side Connection:

```
public class Connection {

    private Socket connection;
    private ObjectInputStream ois;
    private ObjectOutputStream oos;
    private AsymmetricalEncryption encryption;

    public Connection(Socket connection) {
        try {
            this.connection = connection;
            this.oos = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            this.ois = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            encryption = new RSAEncryption();
            // sending the public key
            oos.writeUTF(encryption.encodeBase64PublicKey(encryption.publicKey));
            oos.flush();
            // read sharedKey
            String encodedKey = ois.readUTF();
            encryption.setSharedKey(encryption.decodeBase64PublicKey(encodedKey, "RSA"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Connection(Socket connection, String encryptionMethod) {
        try {
            //this.connection = connection;
            this.ois = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            this.oos = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            encryption = AsymmetricalEncryptionFactory.getAsymmetricalEncryption(encryptionMethod);
            // sending the public key
            oos.writeUTF(encryption.encodeBase64PublicKey(encryption.publicKey));
            oos.flush();
            // read sharedKey
            String encodedKey = ois.readUTF();
            encryption.setSharedKey(encryption.decodeBase64PublicKey(encodedKey, encryptionMethod));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Response request(Request request){
        try {
            byte[] encryptedStringResponse = encryption.encrypt(request.toJSONString());
            oos.write(encryptedStringResponse);
            oos.flush();
            byte[] response =  ois.readAllBytes();
            response = encryption.decrypt(response);
            return new Response(new JSONObject(new String(response)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

At the moment i don't know why but when i send data from client to server the server says that a new connection has come but hangs on doing nothing while in the client side it says that the data has been sent.

Comment: In the `encrypt` method, the ciphertext is converted to a string with a character encoding. This corrupts the data. Furthermore the plaintext is Base64 encoded _before_ encryption, which makes little sense. The Base64 encoding should take place _after_ encryption, which would also fit better to the `decrypt` method (where the ciphertext is Base64 decoded before decryption).

Comment: So i should send byte[] instead of string and move encrypting before encoding, right? Do you know any other better way for establishing secure connections in java?

Comment: Thank you but, i already fixed the problem and started using `byte[] encryptedStringRequest = (byte[]) ois.readObject();` in the server and `oos.writeObject(encryptedStringResponse); oos.reset();` in the client, anyway this project can have a lot of different clients coded in different languages that use different frameworks, for example nodejs, at the current state using `ObjectOutputStream` won't work with different languages, should i use a `BufferedReader` instead?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to use TLS. In Java, you can create server and client socket factories [through an `SSLContext`.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html)

It would be unethical to try to devise your own cryptosystem and apply it to any data that other people are trusting you to secure. But if you are doing this for fun, as a learning exercise, and don't intend to do any real work with it, you can make the most of your effort by trying to learn how real cryptosystems work.

RSA is relatively slow, and the amount of data that can be encrypted in each operation is limited by the RSA key size that you choose. It is [best used to encrypt another key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) for a symmetric cipher like AES. This is how RSA is used in any widely accepted encryption scheme. Large amounts of application data can then encrypted quickly with the symmetric cipher, using a key exchanged via RSA.

Comment: Ok the problem is that the clients that connect to my server can be coded in many different languages, usually javascript with node, using your approach can i still do this?

Comment: @AndreaDattero Yes, every platform will support TLS, so you don’t have to implement a protocol yourself for each client platform.

Comment: And TLS itself is an example that uses public key cryptography such as RSA to exchange a private key for use in a symmetric cipher such as AES.